# Angular2: How to dynamically set data binding variables on input elements?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

In a component template in angular2, it is possible to add a data-binding variable to an input element:

```
<input name="title" #title>
```

Also, we can dynamically set the property value like this:

```
<input name="{{ name }}" #title>
```

However, how can we dynamically set these data-binding variables?
For example, is it possible to do something like this?

```
<input name="{{ name }}" #{{ name }}>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What would you need this for?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I am trying to dynamically create a form and would like to assign variable names dynamically. So that I only have to change the number of variables in my event handler on submit button. I can probably also explore variable length arguments to the event handler function if angular supports it.

Comment: You can pass additional parameters to event handlers.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I am completely new to angular (Only started reading it some 3 hours ago) so apologies if I am suggesting too far fetched usecase. I am basically playing with angular :p

Comment: Actually I can imagine use cases, also dynamic forms.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer So any suggestions how else can I do this?

Comment: I would need more details what you actually try to accomplish.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I am trying to keep my form configuration in an array of jsons (which can be programmatically managed) which I can pass to my Component template. In the template I can run a ngFor on conf. and create input elements. Outside of the ngFor I intend to keep a single submit button, which on click will pass all the input elements to the event handler function (variable length arguments will be really helpful for this) where I can read their values.

Comment: I haven't investigated dynamic forms yet. There were some questions with elaborate answers not too long ago.

Comment: @Surender Thakran : You need to utilize the ng-model directive to get this done.

Answer (score 1):

No, template variables can't even be set to arbitrary values and also having the name variable isn't supported.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind variable to input value like this:

```
<input name="{{ name }}" ng-model="name">
```